# How do i make an if statement referring to an aray?

Tags: python

So as part of a program i need a line where if the input is not in a certain array the code wont carry on.

The best way to explain it is with a game of cards. You cant play a card that isnt in your hand(array) What would this look like in code form?

```
eg. if cardplayed (is not in) (myhand):
print("ect ect")
```

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses and also `is`. You also need to indent the `print` call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: @Lix but they're not trying to find the index, they just want to check membership

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `not in` operator:

```py
if cardplayed not in myhand:
    print("etc etc")
```

The opposite would be

```py
if cardplayed in myhand:
   print("I have this card, man")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regardless of if `myhand` is a `numpy` array or not:**

```
if cardplayed not in myhand:
    print("ect ect")
```

Comment: I don't think you need to include the `numpy` package for this... It can be done in python itself...

Comment: the OP did not mention if it is a numpy or not.

Comment: So how would i loop this until a card is picked that is acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Having a sequence, (a list in this example), one may check if an item is present within that sequence using the `not in` operator: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

```py
hand = ['Card1', 'Card2', 'Card3']
card = 'Other card'
if card not in hand:
    print('Breaking...')
```